# Remotely (long-distance) triggering a 12V solenoid?

Tags: rf, relay, solenoid

I have purchased a "1CH DC12V 2000M Long Range RF Remote Controller Kit" - this is a remote relay.  With this gear, I have to power both the receiver and the load with 12V sources.

I'm trying to remotely trigger a 12V solenoid, where the solenoid/receiver are both battery-powered.  The total setup must also remain as lightweight as possible.

Is there a way to configure this with a single battery, so that I can minimize the weight of the setup?

Update:

**Solenoid current**: not specified - Rated Voltage : DC12V; Power : 17W

**Receiver current**: Standby ≤10mA, Working ≤128mA

**On Time**: <1s

**Standby Time**: ~10 minutes minimum, but longer is better to minimize cost of recharges/replacements

Comment: And the solenoid current is? The load current is? The receiver current? (with the solenoid off, i.e. in standby) The required ON time under battery power? The required standby time under battery power?

Comment: The receiver and solenoid can use the same battery, simply by wiring them in parallel. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-5/what-are-series-and-parallel-circuits/

Comment: @BrianDrummond - updated :)

Comment: Hmmm a standby time of ten minutes eh? OK so after 10 minutes the battery is dead so you walk out to the battery and replace it. 5 minutes there and 5 minutes back equals ten minutes. You have a job for life.

Comment: @Andyaka Hours/Days/Weeks is better, but that's the (absurdly low) minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you're drawing no more than 1.7A@12VDC while "active" (solenoid on), and ~128mA while in 'standby.'

If you used [this 7.0Ah 12V lead-acid battery](http://www.tractorsupply.com/tsc/product/mighty-mule-12v-replacement-battery-fm150?cm_vc=-10005) (fits in one hand & weighs about 2-3lbs, iirc), that would give you ~4hrs of 'hold time' with the solenoid constantly active, or ~54hrs of 'standby' time.

You could also use larger/multiple lead-acid batteries (heavier, but longer-running), or use Li-Ion/LiPO battery packs (light & high-energy, but costlier) to change the balance of size/weight/power/cost to better suit your specific design budget/goals.